# CORS - Unable to logout from application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am doing a proof of concept on AngularJS and SpringMVC 5.x, Tomcat and single-sign-on (SSO) to login and logout from the application. When session is timed-out or Invalid session, the application is not redirected to login page. I am getting CORS error message.

Here is the sample JavaScript code for Invalid Session and Session timeout, please help how to apply CORS on the below code.

```
//Invalid Session 
TestApp.factory('respInterceptor', function($location, $window, $cookies) {
return {
response: function(resp) {
//console.log(" Test : " + JSON.stringify(resp));
return resp;
},
responseError : function(error) {
console.log(" Error >>> : "+error.status )
if(error.status == 401 || error.status == 302) {
$cookies.JSESSIOINID = '';
console.log("invalid session");
window.location = "http://login.boshiftdev.com/app/ui/login.jsp";
}
}
};
})



//Session Timeout
$scope.logout = function() { $cookies.JSESSIOINID = '';
console.log("logout"); 
$http({
method: 'POST',
url: contextURL+'/logout',
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
params: {data: $rootScope.userSession }
}).
success (function(data) {
$rootScope.userSession = null; $window.location = 'login.jsp';
window.location = ""
}).
error (function(data) {
$rootScope.userSession = null; $window.location= 'login.jsp';
console.error('');
});
}
```

[image: CORS Error]

Comment: When there is no user Intervention on the application for 20 minutes, the session expires and while clicking on any of the links it is not redirected to the logout page and I see the CORS error message (in the developer tools).

I also have a popup window for the session time extension having Continue and Exit button (written in Javascript). If I click on the Exit button, it is not redirecting to the logout page. Here too I see the same CORS error message.

The Application and Logout page are two different domain URLs. In this application, we use SSO for login and logout.